# Place for Instant Execution

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange

Is there a place in Stackoverflow where I can directly execute my codes like below some of them:

1. Regex Expressions
2. Java scripts
3. Small .Net Expressions
4. T-Sql

Comment: Not on Stack Overflow, but the net is brimming with Online IDEs.

Comment: [jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net) is good for JavaScript, HTML and CSS live examples.

Comment: http://ideone.com/ lets you run snippets online in a lot of languages.

Comment: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) for SQL related stuff. & [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to check regex

Comment: There's http://repl.it for things like Python, lolcode etc ...

Comment: I was hoping for a quite different question when I first read the title...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a small list of some live coding sites for you to test:

- Regular Expressions1 - http://regexpal.com/
- Regular Expressions2 - http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html
- Regular Expressions3 - http://www.regexr.com
- Ruby - http://tryruby.org/levels/1/challenges/0
- Javascript - http://jsfiddle.net/
- Several languages1 - http://ideone.com/
- Several languages2 - http://codepad.org/

I hope it helps.

Comment: `regexr.com` is another tool to test out regular expressions.

Comment: just added to the list, @nickb!

Answer (score 2):

You can do a lot of things with code on Stack Overflow, but executing is not one of them.

That's why you (should) have a compiler or interpreter.  If you encounter any problems with the code, you can ask about it on Stack Overflow.

Comment: "*You can do a lot of things with code on Stack Overflow*" - Heh, not really =)  You can pretty much just...display it.

Comment: @jadarnel27 Edit it, delete it, criticize it, improve it, indent it, reformat it, refactor it, reorganize it, comment it, ... :)